# Dataframe to multiIndex for sktime format

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sktime

I have a multivariate time series data which is in this format(pd.Dataframe with index on Time),

[image: Existing format]

I am trying to use [sktime](https://sktime.org), which requires the data to be in multi index [format](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/examples/AA_datatypes_and_datasets.html#Section-1.2:-Time-series-panels---the-). On the above if i want to use a rolling window of 3 on above data. It requires it in this format. Here pd.Dataframe has multi-index on (instance,time)

[image: Desired format]

I was thinking if it is possible to transform it to new format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** here's a more straightforward and probably faster solution using row indexing

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':range(5),
    'a':[f'a{i}' for i in range(5)],
    'b':[f'b{i}' for i in range(5)],
})

w = 3
w_starts = range(0,len(df)-(w-1)) #start positions of each window

#iterate through the overlapping windows to create 'instance' col and concat
roll_df = pd.concat(
    df[s:s+w].assign(instance=i) for (i,s) in enumerate(w_starts)
).set_index(['instance','time'])

print(roll_df)
```

Output

```
                a   b
instance time        
0        0     a0  b0
         1     a1  b1
         2     a2  b2
1        1     a1  b1
         2     a2  b2
         3     a3  b3
2        2     a2  b2
         3     a3  b3
         4     a4  b4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to achieve the desired result:

```
# Create the instance column
instance = np.repeat(range(len(df) - 2), 3)

# Repeat the Time column for each value in A and B
time = np.concatenate([df.Time[i:i+3].values for i in range(len(df) - 2)])

# Repeat the A column for each value in the rolling window
a = np.concatenate([df.A[i:i+3].values for i in range(len(df) - 2)])

# Repeat the B column for each value in the rolling window
b = np.concatenate([df.B[i:i+3].values for i in range(len(df) - 2)])

# Create a new DataFrame with the desired format
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Instance': instance, 'Time': time, 'A': a, 'B': b})

# Set the MultiIndex on the new DataFrame
new_df.set_index(['Instance', 'Time'], inplace=True)
new_df
```

[image: The output dataframe]